# Apache virtualhost on another port

Tags: apache, virtualhost, lan

I have mamy virtualhosts on Apache server (Arch Linux) and they are on hosts like 127.0.0.2, 127.0.0.10 and so on. One of them i want to make available from local network, so I could use address like 192.168.1.100 to get resources from that server, but I don't want to use default port. Now I have such configuration on /etc/httpd/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8324>
   DocumentRoot "/home/dominik/Dropbox/dev/SOMEAPP/root"
   <Directory /home/dominik/Dropbox/dev/SOMEAPP/root>
       DirectoryIndex index.php
       Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews +Includes
       AllowOverride All
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
       Require all granted
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

It works perfect on local machine using localhost or 127.0.0.1, but when using lan address on port 8324, i get default apache site (like I make request on port 80)

```
curl 127.0.0.1:8324
```

HTML from SOMEAPP is returned

```
curl 192.168.1.100:8324
```

Default Apache index is returned

My /etc/hosts:

```
#
# /etc/hosts: static lookup table for host names
#

#<ip-address>   <hostname.domain.org>   <hostname>
127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain   localhost
#::1             localhost.localdomain   localhost
127.0.0.2       xx.tu                   xx.tu       
# 127.0.0.3     xxxxx.tu                xxxxx.tu       
127.0.0.4       xxxxxxxx.tu             xxxxxxxx.tu
127.0.0.5       xxxxxxxxxxx.tu           xxxxxxxxxxx.tu
127.0.0.6   xxxxx.tu        xxxxx.tu
127.0.0.10  xxxxxxx         xxxxxxxx
```

I'd be glad if someone have some idea. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, this is not a programming question. Maybe you want to migrate it to SuperUser?

Comment: Yes. I'm sorry. I really had to put it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably a SuperUser question, anyway:

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.100:8324>
   DocumentRoot "/home/dominik/Dropbox/dev/SOMEAPP/root"
   <Directory /home/dominik/Dropbox/dev/SOMEAPP/root>
       DirectoryIndex index.php
       Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews +Includes
       AllowOverride All
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
       Require all granted
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

p.s.  you might want to modify your httpd configuration to avoid receiving the default apache index when you call the apache server with an Ip which doesn't correspond to any defined virtualhost

Comment: Solved so simple. Thanks.